# Towards north or towards the north

Tags: grammar, articles

Let's say there is a region with two parts, *north and south*. This region has a **railway** and has been urbanized, which can now travel towards northern train line, crossing over a river.
[image]

> The railway from the southern part of XYZ region has just been extended, which can cross over a river **towards the northern train line**.

Or

> The railway from the southern part of XYZ region has just been extended, which can cross over a river **towards northern train line.** (please see the picture on the right)

(Added sentence after the comments and an answer)

*The railway from the southern part of XYZ region has just been extended, **which crosses over a river towards north.**

Comment: This is not really a question about directions or the word 'north'.  "northern train line" is a noun phrase; follow the rules for definite articles with noun phrases.

Comment: Also potentially helpful: _...which can cross over a river **northward**._

Comment: The way you are using "northern train line" is very atypical, and I'm having trouble really understanding the objective.  However, I can respond to the title if that is really what you're asking.  "Towards north" is a compass heading from your current position.  Go in that heading to move in a northerly direction.  "The north" would refer to a place located north of you and probably not contiguous.  "Towards the north" would refer to heading towards that place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, since you are designating a specific reference you should use "***the***"

> cross over a river towards **the** northern train line

Expressed in this way, it may mean that there is *different* train line which lies further north.
To say it is the *same* train line extending north, you might say

> cross over a river **on** the train line **north**

Since you are referring to the railway (route) and not just the train itself, it might be more natural to say

> which **crosses** over a river

since the railway actually *does cross* the river, stating *ability* ("***can***") is awkward.

To express action *and* direction, a native might simply say

> cross**es** over a river **going** north.

**[ADDITIONAL EDIT]**

> They went **north**.
>   They went **going north**.
>   They went **towards** ***the*** **north**.
>   They went **northward**.

Thw way your new sentence is constructed, you are saying the railway crosses over the northern side of the river.  "***Towards***" only describes the direction faced, you need a verb to show movement.

> which crosses over a river and ***travels north***.
>   which crosses over a river and ***goes north***.
>   which crosses over a river and ***goes towards the north***.

Comment: I have added a new sentence, I'm clarifying it if it's correct now... thx